# Centrify: install using script in macOS 10.15

Tags: bash, install, script

We were used to install Centrify using a simple script launched from KACE:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/installer -pkg CentrifyDC-5.5.2-x86_64.pkg -target /
```

Starting from Catalina, it seems that the script installs Centrify (I can find files and folders in the hdd) but the entry in the System Preferences (that is the join assistant) does not appear and also checking in the file system I cannot find the correct application to launch it.
If I install Centrify using the same .pkg file but in the interactive way (with the GUI) everything works smoothly. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Lacking that package, I would look in `/var/log/install.log` after you try the command. It should log tons of details and all failures

Comment: (Also is this your KACE? https://www.quest.com/kace/ )

Comment: yes, it's that KACE. Anyway I understood the guilty: when I run manually, I get a popup saying "Terminal would like to administer your computer / Allow / OK". I guess the script cannot go through this and therefore fails. Terminal should be put in some groups in the mac settings for security & privacy, but I did not find any way to do that programmatically

Comment: Aah, so you’re fighting the user approved security controls, and not just a package error at this point...

Comment: yes, this is what I discovered (apologies, pretty new to this). It seems there's no way apart from using an MDM, right? I'd need this to upgrade the Centrify agent before people upgrade to Big Sur, but at this point the only way would be placing the .pkg on their desktop and ask them to launch the update....

Comment: Yes, yes and you’re doing great @maurice77 - you very much want to re-evaluate your MDM choices before you jump to Big Sur. Reach out to Apple Business pronto would be my advice. https://www.apple.com/business/